# INTRA-cluster and inter-cluster distance

Tags: clustering

Thank you for your reply

I have generated a valid partition using the following code

IDX = kmeans(data(:, 1:end-1),k,'replicates',10,'EmptyAction','drop');

and I am comparing the intra and inter-cluster distances from IDX only with the results of kmeans provided in the paper

If you want, I can provide you all the code that I am using.

thank you again for your reply

Comment: This question is not answerable in its current form. It isn't clear if you want coding help (off-topic here, but maybe OK on SO); code check (off-topic here, but maybe OK on codereview.SE); help w/ understanding k-means & related metrics; or help understanding some paper. We don't have your data, so we can't reproduce your result. We also don't know what is going on in "most of the papers", since we don't know what they are.

Comment: I don't think you can expect answers on these sites either. There are too many open factors, such as whether your data is normalized (which obviously will have an impact on distances).

Comment: Clustering algorithm in the paper involves randomness - so result of algorithm work is also random and differs for different runs of the algorithm. If you problem is that distance calculation for your version and authors version is different, you need to provide more details.